# DLR Mascot asteroid lander's unusual "torque wheel-based" propulsion system

Tags: asteroid, jaxa, mascot

Soon the Japanese Hayabusa 2 mission will release the German "Mascot" Lander onto the surface of the asteroid. The small box shaped lander then impacts the surface and preforms science experiments. [According to the mission specifications, it's supposed to preform science at 3 different locations on the surface.](https://m.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Engineering_Technology/Hera/MASCOT-2_facts_and_figures)  In order to move from location to location, it uses a spinning wheel to impart torque and "flick" the lander to a different spot.

Question: have any other landers used a tourqe wheel to move across the surface of something? If so, which ones.
Thanks
[Video of internals](https://youtu.be/n57_UmNH62I)

Comment: this kind of thing? https://youtu.be/n_6p-1J551Y?t=125

Comment: @uhoh yep, that's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If JAXA successfully deploys MASCOT, it will be the first lander to use "torque wheel based" propulsion.  It is not, however, the first lander to be designed with such a system.  JAXA's previous Hayabusa mission had the [MINERVA lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayabusa#MINERVA_mini-lander) on board, which intended to use an "internal fly-wheel assembly" to flick itself across the surface, but it failed to deploy properly and escaped the asteroid.

The concept of a hopping lander is not entirely new.  The [PROP-F Phobos Hopper](http://cyberneticzoo.com/walking-machines/1983-7-prop-f-phobos-hopper-soviet/) was carried aboard the soviet [Phobos 2 mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobos_2).  This lander was similar in concept to the MINERVA and MASCOT landers, but used a spring-loaded foot pad to launch itself.  The lander never saw action as communications with Phobos 2 were lost before the lander could be deployed.

JAXA's affinity for low-gravity "Hoppers" has inspired future mission concepts as well.  A research team (possibly based at Cornell university) has done work in designing a small in-situ data providing lander, topically named [PANIC](http://www.spaceflightinsider.com/missions/solar-system/panic-lander-revolutionize-asteroid-research/), that will move around an asteroid by hopping.  It is unclear from the limited information about this design whether it will use internal fly-wheels, but it is a likely candidate.